# File Mappingでのアクセス中に他から削除された場合などについて

Tags: c++, winapi

Windows APIのCreateFileMapping()/MapViewOfFile()でファイルの読み出しをする場合で、他プロセスからの書き込みや削除がありうる状況(それらを妨げてはならない状況)での処理について質問します。

1. MapViewOfFile()で取得したポインタでファイルの内容にアクセスしたとき、その直前までに他のプロセスがファイルを削除したりファイルを切り詰めたりしてその位置に相当するファイルのデータがなくなっていた場合、何が起こりますか? CreateFileMapping() にPAGE_READONLY、PAGE_READWRITE、PAGE_WRITECOPY のいずれを渡すかで違いはありますか? なお、当プロセスでCreateFileMapping()に渡すハンドルをCreateFile()で作成したとき、`FILE_SHARE_DELETE | FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE`を指定した(他プロセスからの書き込みや削除を許す旨指定した)ものとします。
2. 私の予想は「削除されても何も起こらず正しく読み込まれるが、切り詰められたときはEXCEPTION_IN_PAGE_ERRORの構造化例外が発生する」ですが、EXCEPTION_IN_PAGE_ERROR は C++の`try {} catch (...) {}`ではキャッチできず、SEHを使うしかありませんか?
3. このような状況ではVSSを使うのが適切なのかも知れません。VSSでスナップショットを取得してからCreateFileMapping()を使用する場合、ファイルをいったんコピーする必要がありますか? パフォーマンスが重要なため、コピーは避けたいと思っています。

追記: そもそも「削除できない」ということが判明しました。検証用コードを追記します。

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlconv.h>

#define USE_MMAP

int main()
{
    static const _TCHAR filename[] = _T("test.txt");
    static const char dummydata[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    const auto hCreate = ::CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    ATLENSURE(hCreate != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
    DWORD dwWritten;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) ATLENSURE(::WriteFile(hCreate, dummydata, sizeof(dummydata) - 1, &dwWritten, NULL) && dwWritten == sizeof(dummydata) - 1);
    ATLENSURE(::CloseHandle(hCreate));


    const auto hFile = ::CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_DELETE | FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    ATLENSURE(hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
#ifdef USE_MMAP
    const auto hMap = ::CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL);
    ATLENSURE(hMap != NULL);
    const auto pMap = (LPCSTR)::MapViewOfFile(hMap, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);
#endif

    std::string cmd = std::string("del ");
    cmd += CT2A(filename);
    system(cmd.data()); // アクセスが拒否されました。

#ifdef USE_MMAP
    std::cout << pMap[10000] << std::endl;
#endif
}
```

Comment: そもそも`1`の現象(Open中ファイルの他プロセスからの削除やサイズ縮小)を発生させられるのでしょうか？ [Creating a View Within a File](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-a-view-within-a-file)のサンプルを調整して質問の条件に合わせてみたのですが、`MapViewOfFile`と`UnmapViewOfFile`の間にキー入力待ちを挿入し、その時点で別プロセスから[CreateFileW function (fileapi.h)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew)の`TRUNCATE_EXISTING`や[DeleteFileW function (fileapi.h)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-deletefilew)を呼び出してもエラーで削除や縮小は出来ませんでした。質問の現象を起こさせるサンプルを提示あるいはリンク紹介してもらった方が良いと思われます。

Comment: 検証頂いたようでありがとうございます。興味深い結果ですね。CreateFileMappingするとFILE_SHARE_DELETEは無効になるようです。私の知る限り、Microsoftのドキュメントには記載がないと思います。